# How to Open new static page useing button click in Bada

Tags: bada

I have put image in header with button and click on button then open a new window.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Right now, it's not even a question. What are you trying to do and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You should construct your new window (exactly form) some where in your code then attack an event listener to your header button, then into your listener code block use your application frame like this:

```
Frame *pFrame = Application::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame();
```

then use this method to make your Form active and visible:

```
result r;
r = pFrame->AddControl(*pForm1); //pForm1 is your constructed new form
  pFrame->SetCurrentForm(*pForm1);
  pForm1->RequestRedraw();
```